# Getting APCUPSD working with PowerChute (pcnet)

Tags: apc, apc-smart-ups, apcupsd

After configuring apcupsd and starting the service the service eventually times out and reports `Warning communications lost with UPS`.

The ups is configured with the IP of the client and the client is configured with the correct passphrase (working on other machines which are using the PCNS software)

**Environment**

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

**UPS**

```
Model:  Smart-UPS RT 8000 XL
Position:   TOWER
Serial Number:  IS10xxxxxxxx
Firmware Revision:  477.18.W
Manufacture Date:   12/02/10
```

**apcupsd.conf**

```
UPSCABLE ether
UPSTYPE pcnet
DEVICE 10.1.1.11:admin:WVAVWFr5FV6SRq7u
LOCKFILE /var/lock
SCRIPTDIR /etc/apcupsd
PWRFAILDIR /etc/apcupsd
NOLOGINDIR /etc
ONBATTERYDELAY 6
BATTERYLEVEL 5
MINUTES 3
TIMEOUT 0
ANNOY 300
ANNOYDELAY 60
NOLOGON disable
KILLDELAY 0
NETSERVER on
NISIP 127.0.0.1
NISPORT 3551
EVENTSFILE /var/log/apcupsd.events
EVENTSFILEMAX 10
UPSCLASS standalone
UPSMODE disable
STATTIME 0
STATFILE /var/log/apcupsd.status
LOGSTATS on
DATATIME 0
```

**Notes**

I have purged the ubuntu apcupsd package and built/installed from source with `enable-pcnet` configure flag.

I have restarted the service while looking at the tcpdump for `host 10.1.1.11`. All I can see is packets coming from the UPS but none going to it. I don't think apcupsd is even trying to communicate with it. Perhaps the DEVICE line is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything pointed to an auth issue. I upgraded the controller firmware to 5.1.7 and reset the pass phrase and everything works great!